# get the value from columns in two files

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, grep

My original observations look like that:

```
name Analyte
spring 0.1
winter 0.4
```

To calculate p-value I did bootstrapping simulation:

```
name Analyte
spring 0.001
winter 0
spring 0
winter 0.2
spring 0.03
winter 0
spring 0.01
winter 0.02
spring 0.1
winter 0.5
spring 0
winter 0.04
spring 0.2
winter 0
spring 0
winter 0.06
spring 0
winter 0
.....
```

Now I want to calculate empirical p-value: In original data winter Analyte = 0.4 - if in bootstrapped data winter analyte was >=0.4 (for example 1 time) and bootstrapping was done (for example 100 times), then empirical p-value for winter analyte is calculated:

> 1/100 = 0.01

(How many times data was the same or higher than in original data
divided by total number of observations)
For spring analyte p-value is:

> 2/100 = 0.02

I want to calculate those p-values with awk.
My solution for spring is:

```
awk -v VAR="spring" '($1==VAR && $2>=0.1) {n++} END {print VAR,"p-value=",n/100}'
```

spring p-value= 0.02
The help I need is to pass original file (with names spring and winter and their analytes, observations **and** number of observations) into awk and assign those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Explanation and script content:

#### Run it like: `awk -f script.awk original bootstrap`

```
# Slurp the original file in an array a
# Ignore the header

NR==FNR && NR>1 {

# Index of this array will be type
# Value of that type will be original value

    a[$1]=$2
    next
}

# If in the bootstrap file value
# of second column is greater than original value

FNR>1 && $2>a[$1] { 

# Increment an array indexed at first column
# which is nothing but type

    b[$1]++
}

# Increment another array regardless to identify
# the number of times bootstrapping was done
{
    c[$1]++
}

# for each type in array a

END {
    for (type in a) {

# print the type and calculate empirical p-value 
# which is done by dividing the number of times higher value
# of a type was seen and total number of times
# bootstrapping was done. 

        print type, b[type]/c[type]
    }
}
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat original 
name Analyte
spring 0.1
winter 0.4

$ cat bootstrap 
name Analyte
spring 0.001
winter 0
spring 0
winter 0.2
spring 0.03
winter 0
spring 0.01
winter 0.02
spring 0.1
winter 0.5
spring 0
winter 0.04
spring 0.2
winter 0
spring 0
winter 0.06
spring 0
winter 0

$ awk -f s.awk original bootstrap 
spring 0.111111
winter 0.111111
```

#### Analysis:

```
Spring Original Value is 0.1
Winter Original Value is 0.4
Bootstrapping done is 9 times for this sample file
Count of values higher than Spring original value = 1
Count of values higher than Winter's original value = 1
So, 1/9 = 0.111111
```

Answer (score 2):

#### this works for me, (GNU awk 3.1.6):

```
FNR == NR {
     a[$1] = $2
     next
}

$2 > a[$1] {
    b[$1]++
    }

{
    c[$1]++
}

END {
    for (i in a) print i, "p-value=",b[i]/c[i]
    }
```

..output is:

```
winter p-value= 0.111111
spring p-value= 0.111111
```